# app.module.ts > APP_INITIALIZER dependent on another

Tags: angular, module

I need an `APP_INITIALIZER` to get data from a previous `APP_INITIALIZER` SERVICE. In this case, to set the language.

I have a previous initializer, that loads the

```
export function configLoaderFactory(provider: ConfigLoaderService) {
    return () => provider.load();
}

export function settingsLoaderFactory(provider: SettingsLoaderService) {
    return () => provider.load();
}

export function translateHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/');
}
```

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [WpaComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot({
            mode: 'ios',
            rippleEffect: false,
            statusTap: false
        }),
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: translateHttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MbscModule,
        WpaDirectivesModule
    ],
    providers: [
        AppInjector,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        AppVersion,
        
        Keyboard,
        
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy},
        
        
        ConfigLoaderService,
        {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configLoaderFactory, deps: [ConfigLoaderService, AppVersion], multi: true},
        
        SettingsLoaderService,
        {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: settingsLoaderFactory, deps: [SettingsLoaderService, StorageService], multi: true},

        
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (translate: TranslateService, config: ConfigLoaderService) => {
                return () => {
 console.log(`config.getConfig()-> `, config.getConfig()); // This yields null because it is not loaded yet
                    
    /*              if (config.getConfig().force_language) {
                        
                        translate.setDefaultLang(config.getConfig().force_language_locale);
                        translate.use(config.getConfig().force_language_locale);
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                };
            },
            multi: true,
            deps: [TranslateService, ConfigLoaderService]
        },
        
        AuthGuardService,
        ApiService
    ], exports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule,
        FormsModule,
        MbscModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicStorageModule,
        WpaDirectivesModule,
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
```

I can not access `ConfigLoaderService`.

Is there any way to either phase the loading, or wait for the loading of the file (it's a small json file) in `ConfigLoaderService`?

Comment: If you need to load data **before** the Angular application is started, then you should perform the loading in the `main.ts` file where `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule()` is called. You would lazy load the data, and then bootstrap the main module.

Comment: Yeah, but that is not how it's supossed to work. That seems hacky. And it doesn't solve the main question point, which is how to deal with dependent services that are bootstrapped as APP_INITIALIZER. Thanks for trying to help, though :).